# Replacing all the §'s in a string

Tags: php

Say I have a string such as "&8My§4Name§2Is§7John"

I want to replace all the §'s with &'s however the regular replace functions don't seem to be working.

```
$string = "&8My§4Name§2Is§7John";
$string = preg_replace("/§/", "&", $string);
echo $string;
```

On the HTML page the echo comes out as:

```
&8My�4Name�2Is�7John
```

EDIT:
It seems to work outside a function, when the string is passed into the function something seems to get scrambled.

Comment: `str_replace` is enough.

Comment: see here: preg_replace  https://eval.in/96118  and str_replace https://eval.in/96119 both are giving your expected output

Comment: It has exactly the same effect.

Comment: my output is : `&8My&4Name&2Is&7John`

Comment: @AwladLiton Thats strange, I have tried it on 2 different PHP installed, both v 5.5 and 5.4 and both result in the same � output.

Comment: http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/ try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$string = "&8My§4Name§2Is§7John";
$string = str_replace("§", "&", $string);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

this wored for me

```
    <?php
$string = "&8My§4Name§2Is§7John";
$string = str_replace('§', '&', $string);
echo $string;
?>
```

if this don´t work try adding a meta tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in your html